# Restoring data to GitLab

Tags: git, postgresql, gitlab

I used GitLab and had a problem.

I decided to install GitLab with Docker.The problem is that I cannot restore data from `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data`

I just moved git-data to `/srv/gitlab/data`

I think there is a problem with PostgreSql, so I did not copy it. When I start GitLab with Docker, I cannot find any repositories.

Should I do something else to restore all data? And how can I restore GitLab user accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I just restored automatically backuped data.